# How can I SELECT all table rows with data to display total number with data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to show the total amount of say people with kittens.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people.kittens WHERE IS NOT NULL");
```

The issue is the field is not set to `NULL` and is either blank or has data. Then I would show the total number with:

```
$Totalpeoplewithkittens = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

I know `mysql_query` is outdated. Just testing/learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT count(kittens) FROM people WHERE kittens > ''");
```

Comment: Don't select everything if you just want the count. That is a waste of resources. MySQL can return the count as a variable.

Comment: agreed...but I edited it afterwards when I realised the better way :)

Answer (score 0):

Use like Select count(*) from...

Comment: He asks to know the condition of not NULL field, not how to count the number of row

Comment: Sorry, but ´SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people.kittens WHERE IS NOT NULL´ return zero rows in this case